# How to pickle closure?

Tags: python, closures, pickle, attributeerror, dill

Example:

```py
import pickle

def function():
    def closure():
        pass
    return closure

pickle.dumps(function())
```

Which yields:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'function.<locals>.closure'
```

There is this question [How to refactor method returning closure to be pickleable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406097/how-to-refactor-method-returning-closure-to-be-pickleable) which has an answer that suggests `import dill as pickle` - but in my case that would require monkey patching.

Since I also found some examples [Can Python pickle lambda functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions) on how to pickle lambda functions (which isn't support by `pickle` out of the box either), I have some hope that there is a way to actually pickle `function()` with stdlib `pickle` - only by refactoring above code example.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the `dill` author. Here's the code you gave, working with `dill`:

```
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> def function():
...   def closure():
...     pass
...   return closure
... 
>>> pickle.dumps(function())
b'\x80\x03cdill._dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill._dill\n_create_code\nq\x01(K\x00K\x00K\x00K\x01KSC\x04d\x00S\x00q\x02N\x85q\x03))X\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>q\x04X\x07\x00\x00\x00closureq\x05K\x02C\x02\x00\x01q\x06))tq\x07Rq\x08c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x05NNtq\tRq\n}q\x0b}q\x0c(X\x0f\x00\x00\x00__annotations__q\r}q\x0eX\x0c\x00\x00\x00__qualname__q\x0fX\x19\x00\x00\x00function.<locals>.closureq\x10u\x86q\x11b.'
>>> _closure = pickle.loads(_)
>>>
```

I'm not sure how this requires a monkey patch... but if this is your use case, then `dill` will work for you.  There are some special cases, such as you are using a package that is using `pickle` specifically, and you can't substitute `dill` for `pickle`. Your options there are: (1) find a code like `multiprocess` that forks `multiprocessing` by replacing `pickle` with `dill`, or (2) leverage the appropriate functions in `dill` to register the needed types in `pickle` using `copyreg` and the `Pickler.dispatch` table.

Comment: Hey thanks :) I apologize for the misunderstanding. My code above is only an example. The monkey patch would be required because it's exactly like you already said: The pickling happens in a package that uses `pickle` specifically. In the example, `import pickle` and `pickle.dumps` are only in the same file for simplicity - and cannot be changed. I'm sorry, I don't understand your (2). Would it be possible to apply that to the example code above?

Comment: What `dill` is doing, essentially, is extending the types of objects that `pickle` knows how to serialize, as one would do with `copyreg`.  So, you should be able, in most cases, to copy the registered serialization function from the `dill.Pickler` dispatch table to `pickle` by using `copyreg` (or otherwise).  Where serialization of a closure is not possible, it's best to substitute the closure with a class that has a `__call__` method -- then the outer function is equivalent to the `__init__` method, and the inner function is equaled to the `__call__` method.